# Erro constante no uso do strptime

Tags: python-2.7, datetime

Caros,

Sempre trabalhei com o strptime sem maiores problemas, mas começou a aparecer um erro que não achei em nenhuma citação:

```
from datetime import datetime
a = "20160228"
date = datetime.strptime(a, "%Y%m%d")
```

Esse é apenas o exemplo e o erro que aparece:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/bruno/PycharmProjects/Shiny/date.py", line 3, in <module>
    date = datetime.strptime(a, '%Y%m%d')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 274, in <module>
    _TimeRE_cache = TimeRE()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 192, in __init__
    self.locale_time = LocaleTime()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 70, in __init__
    self.lang = _getlang()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/_strptime.py", line 29, in _getlang
    return locale.getlocale(locale.LC_TIME)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'getlocale'
```

Agradeço as ajudas.

Comment: Em que momento começou? Usa Linux ou Windows? Por quê ainda usa Python 2 e não Python 3?

Comment: Provavelmente após ter atualizado o Ubuntu 18.04, os scripts que trabalho estão sempre no 2.7, também faço com o 3. Mas esse erro achei muito estranho.

Comment: Isso tem cara de ser algum pacote não instalado no Linux.

Comment: Foi também o que estava imaginando, mas não sei qual pacote, tentei reinstalar vários, mas não muda.